# How to call for Bootstrap Modal on only specific pages using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

I'm successfully using the bootstrap modal package on our website (using wordpress), but the JS is loading on every page, and I only use it on 3 specific pages.  I'm looking for the best way to load the JS *only* on the 3 specific pages in question.  The site in question is: https://www.bakashana.org.
The three pages where the Modals operate are: https://www.bakashana.org/sponsor-a-young-woman,  https://www.bakashana.org/grantees-with-sponsors, and  https://www.bakashana.org/graduates

The Bootstrap package has two files: bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.js.  These files are placed in  the css and js folders respectively in my child theme (/wp-content/themes/astra-child/css and /wp-content/themes/astra-child/js).

The Bootstrap is registered and enqueued in my functions.php file as follows:

```
function themeprefix_bootstrap_modals() {
wp_register_script ( 'modaljs' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', true );
wp_register_style ( 'modalcss' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', '' , '', 'all' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'modaljs' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'modalcss' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeprefix_bootstrap_modals');
```

I'm a novice at JS and don't know where/how to add code to the functions.php file in order to call only for specific pages to load.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand. What does the position of functions.php have to do with JS?

Comment: Isn't this PHP code in your question? You're asking how to generate different HTML code using PHP. This is a PHP and Wordpress question and not a JavaScript and Bootstrap question.

Comment: try something like this: https://mekshq.com/include-javascriptonly-on-specific-wordpress-page-templates/

Comment: and this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I figured it out myself, mostly thanks to this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw6VDOZYqrM

The code uses the if( is_page) as follows:

```
function themeprefix_bootstrap_modals() {
 if( is_page( array (1071, 3725, 3814) ) ) {
wp_register_script ( 'modaljs' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_register_style ( 'modalcss' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', '' , '', 'all' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'modaljs' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'modalcss' );
}
}
```

Comment: You can use the slug too instead of an ID, making it more robust in case of changing IDs.